# unpivot data frame - get original data series

Tags: r

I need to clean up the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(metric=c(10,20,30,40,NA), cnt=c(1,2,1,2,2))
> df
  metric cnt
1     10   1
2     20   2
3     30   1
4     40   2
5     NA   2
```

I need go back to the original data series (un-pivot ??) which would be like below.

```
  metric
1     10 
2     20  
3     20  
4     30  
5     40  
6     40  
7     NA  
8     NA
```

Is this a use case for `tidyr` ? If yes, a `tidyr` based solution would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep`

```
df1 <- data.frame(metric = rep(df$metric, df$cnt))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the function `inverse.rle()` for inverse RLE. See `help("rle")`:

```
df <- data.frame(metric=c(10,20,30,40,NA), cnt=c(1,2,1,2,2))
names(df) <- c("values", "lengths")
inverse.rle(df) # or
data.frame(metric=inverse.rle(df))
```